# ASP.NET Mvc Project EF Code First Enable Migrations Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I am working PluralSight Video Tutorials on ASP.NET MVC. And i couldn't enable migrations on package console..

when i wrote enable-migrations, i am receiving this error;

More than one context type was found in the assembly 'eManager.Web'.
To enable migrations for eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb, use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb.
To enable migrations for eManager.Web.Models.UsersContext, use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager.Web.Models.UsersContext.

when i wrote Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb., i am receiving this error;

The context type 'eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb.' was not found in the assembly 'eManager.Web'.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect that your issue is similar to the one in this question:

[How to Enable Migration to update my database in MVC4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922945/how-to-enable-migration-to-update-my-database-in-mvc4)

Check the selected answer and see if that helps with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the mentioned error "The context type .... was not found" is to select the correct project that holds the context type before running the enable-migration command. You can choose the correct project from the "default project" drop down at the top of Nuget manager tool window.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is simple, just remove the dot (.) at the end of this statement "Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb." and run the package manager console again, the migration should be enabled.