# Enable Migration For Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, migration, asp.net-identity, identity

Hi How To Enable Migration In Asp.Net Identity Application DbContext ?

I Have Project With Some Tables . And Install Identity From Nuget On Them .

My Table Related To Identity User Table .

I Want To Enable Migration For All Project.

Please Help Me .

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Package Manager Console as explain in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx) article.

Sometimes you may have to force the migrations part as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922945/how-to-enable-migration-to-update-my-database-in-mvc4).

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Hope this helps.